Converting a KEM with known associated public key into a signature efficiently
Is there a way that given a KEM and a KEM public key that is bound to a entity to generate signatures efficiently for the entity?
Let's say there exists a publicly known secure and perfectly correct KEM algorithm tuple Gen()->Pub_key, Priv_key; Encap(Pub_key)->Ciphertext, Secret; Decap(Priv_key, Ciphertext)-> Secret.
Alice knows that Bob's public key is Pub_bob and has a copy of said public key. Alice challenges Bob to generate a signature S for a challenge input D. Is there a way for Bob to efficiently generate the signature S for D using the KEM algorithms, knowledge of both Pub_bob and the corresponding KEM private key, and common symmetric primitives*? Assume no other asymmetric primitive is allowed.
*PS: Assume a hash based signature scheme is not allowed. I'm curious about generic and efficient ways to convert asymmetric KEMs into signatures, not trying to recreate SPHINCS+.
